# telebot: How to take a massage in input here?

Tags: python, input, text-to-speech, py-telegram-bot-api

I don't know how to take a message in input here?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['tts'])
def send_text_request(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Write a phrase")
    #input...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage it in two different ways:

- Using custom_state, a new feature from recent releases.
  After `tts` command you can set the state of user at 1, with:

  ```
  bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, '1')
  ```

  and create a new handler:

  ```
  @bot.message_handler(state = '1'):
  def new_function(message):
      ....
  ```

  At the end of the code, add:

  ```
  from telebot import custom_filters
  bot.add_custom_filter(custom_filters.StateFilter(bot))
  ```

  Source: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/custom_states.py
- Another way could be using register_next_step_handler, but honestly I used it only once and then I defined my personal states, because it's a mess. But I itroduce you to it anyway.
  Define a new function that will handle the input from the user, so:

  ```
  def function(message):
      ....
  ```

  Change the code you already wrote with the following:

  ```
  @bot.message_handler(commands=['tts'])
  def send_text_request(message):
      msg = bot.reply_to(message, "Write a phrase")
      bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, function)
  ```

That's all!